# When testing time-dependent code in Python, how can I "speed up time" without skipping seconds?

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest

## Background

I'm currently working on a project for a company where they're trying to create software for managing those TV-screen-sized dynamic video ads that you see in malls.

As part of testing the software, I've learned how to use the [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) package to run a test where the time is frozen at a particular value.  I also see that it has an option to tick the time forward in chunks of seconds:

> #### `tick` argument
>
> FreezeGun has an additional `tick` argument which will restart time at the given value, but then time will keep ticking. This is alternative to the default parameters which will keep time stopped.
>
> #### `auto_tick_seconds` argument
>
> FreezeGun has an additional `auto_tick_seconds` argument which will autoincrement the value every time by the given amount from the start value. This is alternative to the default parameters which will keep time stopped. Note that given `auto_tick_seconds` the `tick` parameter will be ignored.

---

## Problem

The problem with the above solution is that in order to test a full day of the billboard-management software I'm working on, I need both to dramatically speed up the rate of time and also keep the granularity of minutes and seconds, as there are some functions that need to execute seconds or minutes before other functions run.

How can I speed up time without just skipping time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was to extract the core logic (function) that I wanted to test, rather than running the program from its actual in-production entrypoint, and then just have a `while` loop that ticks forward 1 second and then runs the function I want to test, and to have the loop exit when the datetime reaches a particular value:

```
def test_one_day(self):
    initial_datetime = datetime(year=2018, month=12, day=21)

    with freeze_time(initial_datetime) as frozen_datetime:
        # Set up the test here

        while datetime.now() < initial_datetime + timedelta(days=1):
            # Run whatever code you want here

            frozen_datetime.tick()
```